# Less Terse alternative to Advanced Calculus by Folland.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, soft-question

I am currently in an advanced calculus class in university. We use Advanced Calculus by Folland. 
When I try to follow along the book I find that it is not verbose enough, and has too few examples. I can follow/reproduce most of the proofs but when it comes to the applications/ later questions for each section I find it really difficult to do.

Can anyone recommend an alternative/support text that I could follow that would provide my need for more verbose explanation and more examples?

I really don't want to drop the course, but as the material becomes more and more analytic ie, formula based (we started with topology which I loved), I find it hard to get an intuitive feeling for what is going on and I think that will hurt my performance in the course.

Comment: Did you try looking through the advanced calculus texts at your university library? That's the first thing I would have tried, even before getting online and asking for suggestions (since the suggestions might not be books I have access to). Of course, this may have occurred to others in your class, and maybe the pickings at your library have gotten pretty thin by now. In the U.S. Library of Congress classification, you want to browse books roughtly between QA 300 and QA 330.

Answer (score 1):

Try "Functions of Several Real Variables" by Moskowitz and Paliogiannis.